# How to check if select is selected in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How I can check if `select` is selected in AngularJS. I tried to use

```
$scope.$watch
```

On models for these selects but I think this is not efficient.

This is example of my current solution. 
html:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <select ng-model="first">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="second">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
$scope.$watch('first + second', function () {
            if (angular.isDefined($scope.first) &&
                angular.isDefined($scope.second)
                ) {
               alert("user chose from the two drop downs.");
            }

        });
}
```

And here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/atN5n/1/

But I think this solution is not effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it is considered bad form to have watches set up on your controller (they work much better in directives).

In each of your selects you can add

```
<select ng-change="selectChanged()"...
```

Then in your controller you can handle this event, as you were intending to do with your watch

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectChanged = function () {
        if (angular.isDefined($scope.first) &&
            angular.isDefined($scope.second)) {
            alert("user chose from the two drop downs.");
        }
    });
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atN5n/2/)

Here is some more information regarding this: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** AngularJS is providing [`ngFocus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) and [`ngBlur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directives.